# Analysis of the output samples from an autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoders

I am conducting some experiments on an autoencoder as part of my research project. For our first experiment, we have a feedforward neural network (using pytorch), which is being given an input of dimensions $80 \times 1$ and is giving out an output of dimensions $80 \times 1$. The $80$ input random variables are jointly gaussian. The input samples are being generated from a randomly generated block diagonal covariance matrix of size $80 \times 80$ and $0$ mean vector $80 \times 1$.

So first, we are training the autoencoder on some randomly generated samples from this input distribution using mean squared error as the loss function (we are sending the input column by column) and then we plan to train it on KL divergence. After that we will give it some inputs, get the output and analyze the output distribution with respect to the input distribution.

The problem we are facing is as follows:

1. During the training, the covariance matrix of the output distribution is sometimes of rank < 80 and we are getting an error stating that the covariance matrix is not positive definite. We are using `torch.cov()` to generate the covariance matrix
2. What would be the best way to calculate KL divergence in this particular context? We need to use it as a loss function.

This is the code we are using for it right now:

```
loss = torch.distributions.kl.kl_divergence
(
 torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mu1_tensor, cov1_tensor),
 torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mu2, cov2)`
 )
```

Here is another function that we have come across for it.

```
kl_loss = torch.nn.functional.kl_div(output_tensor.log(), input_tensor, reduction='batchmean')
```

Comment: Does your AE ouputs only the mean? Also, the KL as loss is mandatory or you can use maximum likelihood estimation for example?